# mysql COUNT DISTINCT multiple columnes with WHERE

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

I'm attempting to generate data from a single table that creates a report showing how many times locations a,b,c have occurred in the last period (@dt).

I can make the single SELECT query work, but can not figure out how to group them together and generate a full report.  The error is 1241: Operand should contain 1 column, and I've spent an hour working through previous answers, but am completely stuck.

```
SELECT (
SELECT DISTINCT pid, SUM(location like '%a%') FROM db.t WHERE (date > @dt) GROUP BY pid)
 AS 'a', (
SELECT DISTINCT pid, SUM(location like '%b%') FROM db.t WHERE (date > @dt) GROUP BY pid)
 AS 'b', (
SELECT DISTINCT pid, SUM(location like '%c%') FROM db.t WHERE (date > @dt) GROUP BY pid)
 AS 'c';
```

Comment: Since you're using `GROUP BY pid`, it's already `DISTINCT`, you don't need that modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the count per `pid`?  If so, this is a simpler query:

```
 SELECT pid, SUM(location like '%a%') as As,
        SUM(location like '%b%') as Bs,
        SUM(location like '%c%') as Cs
 FROM db.t
 WHERE (date > @dt)
 GROUP BY pid
```

Comment: Beautifully elegant solution, Gordon.  Thank you.